# Magento 1.9: Can't translate order status labels on the order grid?

Tags: magento-1.9, localisation

We can't translate the order status labels on the order grid.
When viewing a specific order, the translation is working as it should be.

Were having a problem with translating the order status labels "Processing", "Canceled" and "Complete" into Swedish. For example, we want to change "Complete" to "Skickad" (Sent in English). Please see the picture below. We have done the necessary changes in "System" => "Order Statuses", but that doesn't change these statuses labels on the grid?!

[image: Edit Order Status]

[image: Order Grid Statuses]

Answer (score 1):

the order labels you try to amend will be applied on frontend, to translate them in backend, you should add these translations via csv, like: `"Complete","Skickad"`.

It can be done applying changes to

```
app/locale/sv_SE/Mage_Adminhtml.csv
```

Hope it helps, have a nice day ;)

Comment: Thanks dsitovs! This makes all the translations works, for example when viewing a specific order, but not on the order grid. Nothing happens on the grid, the statuses stays in English on the grid.

Comment: Found this, that solved the translation problem. Please see comment from Ivan: http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-translate-form-labels-in-magentos-admin-area/